Unable to use .env.production file when running npm run dev:prod
In the .env file I have the variable PORT=4000, in the .env.production file I have PORT=3000.
I configured in package.json as follows:
"dev:prod": "npx nodemon --env=production",

when I have successfully run it on the production environment but still running on port 4000.
I tried every way to reinstall process.env but it didn't work
Here is my code:

I want it when I run npm run dev:prod to run on port 3000 as I set up from the beginning.

Try specifying the dotenv file directly like this: npx nodemon --exec node --env-file=.env.production index.js (or whatever file you want  to run).
